# How to select all fields where a string is common in all the tables in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database where there is 3 tables 'groupstage', 'quarterfinal,' semifinal. All of these table have a column named 'Date'. Now I want to write a query from where I can get all the fields from those tables with a specific date? what should i write it in php?

Comment: Depends on what you do expect. If there is a relashionship between the 3 tables then use a single query with join conditions, or if not, uses 3 distinct queries

Comment: The most common question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, you can write a query which join the 3 tables like :

```
SELECT *
FROM groupstage, quarterfinal, semifinal
WHERE groupstage.date = quarterfinal.date AND quarterfinal.date = semifinal.date
AND date = "YOUR DATE"
```

In php you should just create a var $query = "My query above"